# How can I check if Model.IsValid when I want to have at least one checkbox value be true?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, model

I have a model with many checkboxes.  This model can only be valid if at least one of the boxes has been checked and the date has been selected.  The model looks like this:

```
public class CustomDistricts4Weeks
{
    [DisplayName("002")]
    public bool D2 { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("003")]
    public bool D3 { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("004")]
    public bool D4 { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("005")]
    public bool D5 { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("006")]
    public bool D6 { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("007")]
    public bool D7 { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("ARL")]
    public bool DArl { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("BAR")]
    public bool DBar { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("COL")]
    public bool DCol { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("GER")]
    public bool DGer { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("MEM")]
    public bool DMem { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("LAK")]
    public bool DLak { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("MIL")]
    public bool DMil { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("JAIL")]
    public bool DJail { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("JAILEAST")]
    public bool DJailEast { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("SCCC")]
    public bool DSCCC { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("1USD")]
    public bool D1USD { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("2USD")]
    public bool D2USD { get; set; }
            
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Date Only")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "To Date")]
    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
}
```

I'm sure I can just put [Required] on the ToDate but how can I make sure that at least one of the bools is true? Any number can be true but at least one must be true. I may not be approaching this issue correctly and I would be eager to learn a better approach. My code is working but I am trying to build a validation.

Comment: My bad.  I said model.isvalid when it needs to be modelstate.isvalid.  Also, I did verify that the [Required] fixed my ToDate  requirement.  Now all I need to do is make sure one of the checkboxes is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a custom validation attribute and apply it to the class.

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ModelValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{        
    public ModelValidationAttribute(string errorMessage)
        : base(errorMessage)
    {
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (validationContext.ObjectInstance is CustomDistricts4Weeks model)
        {
            if (model.D2 || model.D3 || model.D4 ...)
            {
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }
        }
        return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

Applying the `ModelValidationAttribute` attribute to the data model class:

```cs
[ModelValidation("Select at least one checkbox")]
public class CustomDistricts4Weeks
{
    [DisplayName("002")]
    public bool D2 { get; set; }

    ...

}
```

The `IsValid()` method of the custom attribute might be changed to use reflection to enumerate all properties in the model. In this case, do not need to use all properties name. Of course only in case all `bool` properties should be tested:

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    var model = (Movie)validationContext.ObjectInstance;
    PropertyInfo[] myPropertyInfo  = model.GetType().GetProperties();
    for (int i = 0; i < myPropertyInfo.Length; i++)
    {
        var prop = myPropertyInfo[i];               
        if (prop.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(bool)) 
            && prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), false).Length > 0
            && prop.GetValue(model) is bool pval && pval)
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;                    
        }
    }
    return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
}
```

Comment: This looks like what I am looking for.  I will test tomorrow and see how it works.  Thanks!

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Thank you so much.

Comment: @Steve Cross: You are welcome! I have added a small change if it's interested.

Comment: Thank you for that. I will look into this a well.